Vercel Prisma Nestjs ошибка при деплое?

[32m[Nest] 3  - [39m12/03/2024, 5:55:30 AM [32m    LOG[39m
[38;5;3m[NestFactory] [39m[32mStarting Nest application...[39m
[31m[Nest] 3  - [39m12/03/2024, 5:55:30 AM [31m  ERROR[39m
[38;5;3m[ExceptionHandler] [39m[31m@prisma/client did not initialize
yet. Please run "prisma generate" and try to import it again. In case
this error is unexpected for you, please report it in
https://pris.ly/prisma-prisma-bug-report[39m Error: @prisma/client did
not initialize yet. Please run "prisma generate" and try to import it
again. In case this error is unexpected for you, please report it in
https://pris.ly/prisma-prisma-bug-report at new PrismaClient
(/var/task/server/node_modules/.prisma/client/default.js:43:11) at new
PrismaService (/var/task/server/src/prisma.service.js:12:21) at
Injector.instantiateClass
(/var/task/server/node_modules/@nestjs/core/injector/injector.js:365:19)
at callback
(/var/task/server/node_modules/@nestjs/core/injector/injector.js:65:45)
at process.processTicksAndRejections
(node:internal/process/task_queues:105:5) at async
Injector.resolveConstructorParams
(/var/task/server/node_modules/@nestjs/core/injector/injector.js:144:24)
at async Injector.loadInstance
(/var/task/server/node_modules/@nestjs/core/injector/injector.js:70:13)
at async Injector.loadProvider
(/var/task/server/node_modules/@nestjs/core/injector/injector.js:97:9)
at async
/var/task/server/node_modules/@nestjs/core/injector/instance-loader.js:56:13
at async Promise.all (index 4) Node.js process exited with exit
status: 1. The logs above can help with debugging the issue.
[32m[Nest] 3  - [39m12/03/2024, 5:55:33 AM [32m    LOG[39m
[38;5;3m[NestFactory] [39m[32mStarting Nest application...[39m
[31m[Nest] 3  - [39m12/03/2024, 5:55:33 AM [31m  ERROR[39m
[38;5;3m[ExceptionHandler] [39m[31m@prisma/client did not initialize
yet. Please run "prisma generate" and try to import it again. In case
this error is unexpected for you, please report it in
https://pris.ly/prisma-prisma-bug-report[39m Error: @prisma/client did
not initialize yet. Please run "prisma generate" and try to import it
again. In case this error is unexpected for you, please report it in
https://pris.ly/prisma-prisma-bug-report at new PrismaClient
(/var/task/server/node_modules/.prisma/client/default.js:43:11) at new
PrismaService (/var/task/server/src/prisma.service.js:12:21) at
Injector.instantiateClass
(/var/task/server/node_modules/@nestjs/core/injector/injector.js:365:19)
at callback
(/var/task/server/node_modules/@nestjs/core/injector/injector.js:65:45)
at process.processTicksAndRejections
(node:internal/process/task_queues:105:5) at async
Injector.resolveConstructorParams
(/var/task/server/node_modules/@nestjs/core/injector/injector.js:144:24)
at async Injector.loadInstance
(/var/task/server/node_modules/@nestjs/core/injector/injector.js:70:13)
at async Injector.loadProvider
(/var/task/server/node_modules/@nestjs/core/injector/injector.js:97:9)
at async
/var/task/server/node_modules/@nestjs/core/injector/instance-loader.js:56:13
at async Promise.all (index 4) Node.js process exited with exit
status: 1. The logs above can help with debugging the issue.
"postinstall": "prisma generate",
"vercel-build": "prisma generate && npx prisma migrate deploy && nest build"

import { Injectable, OnModuleInit } from '@nestjs/common';
import { PrismaClient } from '@prisma/client';

@Injectable()
export class PrismaService extends PrismaClient implements OnModuleInit {
  async onModuleInit() {
    await this.$connect();
  }
}


datasource db {
  provider = "postgresql"
  url      = env("DATABASE_URL")
}

generator client {
  provider = "prisma-client-js"
  output   = "./generated/client"
}

